# Disable the default actionbar on titanium sdk 3.5.0GA

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I updated my Titanium sdk to 3.5.0GA, but there exits a default action bar on every window on Android.
Can anyone please tell me how to permanently disable this default action bar?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Define the settings for your custom theme, for example, your theme at /platform/android/res/values/customtheme.xml like

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Then, activate this theme on your tiapp.xml:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar"/>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

for more see : [Link](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/08/hiding-the-android-actionbar/)

Comment: I get the following error when setting this up with targetSdkVersion="21". I need it on 21 as I am developing for nexus 5 with lollipop. : [ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Comment: i got the error as xml is not well formed. Invalid token