# Hiding Title Bar in Titanium classic android

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-android

I have tried all the possible alternative available on stackoverflow, but it didn't worked. Please let me know if any one has its exact anwser. I am new to titanium framework. My app is completed, but i need to remove by default title bar for titanium classic before uploading it.

Comment: what titanium SDK you are using? Check this Link for more details, hope this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877220/disable-the-default-actionbar-on-titanium-sdk-3-5-0ga/28877518#28877518

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there are 2 ways to do this.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({theme: "Theme.AppCompat.Fullscreen"});
```

Also, it appears you can do this through the TiApp.xml file:

```
...other tiapp file stuff above...
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Fullscreen"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
...other tiapp file stuff below...
```

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Themes

Comment: +1 to the method, but i would use: Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar if you want to keep the status bar.